# How to make model class for dictionary inside array in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

Here is my Json:

```
[ {
    "id": 6854,
    "name": "Laundry Iron",
    "images": [
      {
        "id": 6856,
        "src": "https://abcd.com/yzx/uploads/1750.jpg",
      }
    ], 

     } ]
```

how do we make model class for getting "images":["src": "String" ]?. I want to grab "src" I have tried doing like , but it is not working  :

```
class ProductModel {

    var title: String?
    var regularPrice: Int?
    var salePrice: Int?
    var productDescroption: String?
    var imageUrl: [ImageUrl]?

    init(productJsonL: NSDictionary) {
        self.title = productJsonL["name"] as? String
        self.regularPrice = productJsonL["regular_price"] as? Int
        self.salePrice = productJsonL["sale_price"] as? Int
        self.productDescroption = productJsonL["description"] as? String
         //The problem is here ........
       //self.imageUrl = productJsonL["images"]![0]!["src"] as? String
        self.imageUrl = ImageUrl(imageUrlJson: (productJsonL["images"]![0] as? NSDictionary)!)

    }
}



class ImageUrl {

    var source: String?
    init(imageUrlJson: NSDictionary) {
        self.source = imageUrlJson["src"] as? String
    }

}
```

please correct me with the structure like I have done above so that i can append everything at once in an array ? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: `ProductModel` and your `JSON` have almost nothing in common, where did it come from?

Answer (score 1):

You need `Codable`

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let images: [Image]
}

struct Image: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let src: String    //  or let src: URL
}
```

---

```
do {

    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from: data)
    print(res)

}
catch {

    print(error)
}
```

Comment: `src` can be `URL` (which is `Codable` type).

Comment: @user28434 yes , it could be also